# what is correct Json conversion for string

Tags: javascript, json, angular

[image]

I have the below string and When I try to convert to JSON it if giving me an error

```
const banner =
" { "banners": [ { "startDate": "02/26/2021", "endDate": "12/25/2021","content": "Important changes have been made to the Visit google to review the updated document. <a href="https://www.google11.com" > Google11 </a>" } ] }"
```

It's giving an error for Href this is the code I am using to convert

```
const obj = JSON.parse( banner ? banner.replace(stripTag('div'), '') : banner );
```

Comment: You got your double quotes confused in the `banner` declaration. It's currently a syntax error

Comment: And your code makes no sense. When `banner` is `falsy` you want to use it? And when it's `truthy` you want to string manipulate it in a way that does not make sense to me. What does `stripTag` do even with a `div` string?

Comment: Fix your `banner` declaration and then add it to `JSON.parse`. What is the error?

Comment: Please check I have added image for my string

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking but to parse your string you first need to escape it correctly. I use the back-tick for simplicity here.

Update:
From your edits I can see now that you have a `div` tag in your string that you need to clean up. It entirely depends on how that div got in there in the first place but if it really is only a opening and closing `div` tag that you can simply replace it in your string before parsing the JSON.

The bit you're having trouble with is this bit I think: `<a href = "Any website link" >Conditions</a>`.
To escape this in a string you will have to use double `\\` as I have done below so the string would become `<a href = \\"Any website link\\" >Conditions</a>`

```js
const banner = `<div>{ "banners": [ { "startDate": "02/26/2021", "endDate": "12/25/2021", "content": "<span><strong>Important changes have been made to the Elastic Visit Terms and Conditions to review the updated document. <a href = \\"https://google11.com\\" >Conditions</a> </strong></span> " } ] }</div>`;
const cleanBanner = banner.replace('<div>','').replace('</div>','');
const parsed = JSON.parse(cleanBanner);

console.log(parsed)
```

Comment: I have just updated my string again with the correct URL string , Please check again

Comment: Your "string" is still broken. It's not properly escaped. It would error out because it's not valid javascript...

Comment: Yes what is the issue in string how can I make it work for Json ?

Comment: I showed you in the answer. All elements of your string have to be inside the quotes...

Comment: Please check now I have added an Image of my string

Comment: <div>{ "banners": [ { "startDate": "02/26/2021", "endDate": "12/25/2021",
"content": "<span><strong>Important changes have been made to the Elastic 
Visit Terms and Conditions to review the updated document.
<a href = "Any website link" >Conditions</a> 
</strong></span> " } ] }</div>

Comment: I have added your code mate. Please use human words so we can understand what you're issue is... I have edited the answer one last time.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to add Link but somehow it's not working, <a href = "Any website link" >  any link you can put like www.google11.com and try to convert to JSON and sorry I am new to StackOverflow so I am Learning

Comment: Have you looked at my answer @user1621894? I believe I answered all your questions now?

Comment: I have tried putting \\ but it is not working

Comment: I mean... it's working in the example above. What is not working? What is the error. No one can help you if you're not telling us how :D

Comment: if you put the Href link "https://www.google11.com" will this solution work?

Answer (score -1):

If "the string to be parsed" is a constant-string in your source code, it will necessarily be processed by your language.  So, why not "print it?"  Does the string-value equal what you expected it to be?  Yeah, probably not.

Comment: how to Paser -- Href="www" -- value in Json ?

Comment: <div>{ "banners": [ { "startDate": "02/26/2021", "endDate": "12/25/2021",
"content": "<span><strong>Important changes have been made to the 
Visit Terms and Conditions to review the updated document.
<a href="any website link">Conditions</a> 
</strong></span> " } ] }</div>

Comment: this is my link and I want to convert this to JSON